# Convert mp4 to iso

Tags: convert, mp4

I want to convert an mp4 file from YouTube,to an iso file, so I can burn the file to a dvd. I have searched, but cannot find any software that works with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

[DevedeNG](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/devede) is capable of creating ISO images from media files.  *[Instructions](https://sites.google.com/site/thehomelinuxguide/home/specific-user-questions/devede)*

```
sudo apt install devede
```

[image]

[image]